# Encrypt a string with JavaScript in a Gnome Applet

Tags: javascript, encryption, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

Is there a easy way to encrypt for example a string with AES in a gnome applet written in JavaScript? I can't find a solution in the gnome api reference [1]. I saw that libsecret has a AES implementation for testing purposes [2], but I don't know if I can use it - and if so, how.

The only way I actually can imagine is to use `openssl` over `GLib.spawn_command_line_`.

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/references
[2] https://github.com/GNOME/libsecret/blob/master/libsecret/mock/aes.py

Comment: Can't you find a JavaScript library that performs AES? There should be few out there. Note that I cannot vouch how they perform with regards to side channel attacks, but it should be enough to encrypt a string in place.

Comment: Good idea Maarten, I will give it a try and report my experience here. I don't know why I could not find this approach by myself :) . Thanks!